# Looking for recommended sites to find Joomla and WordPress themes.

Tags: resource-recommendations, website-templates

I am new to pre-defined themes, and I need a theme similar to this image:

[image]

I already searched but I can't find any similar theme, I probably searched in the wrong places.

What websites could you recommend to search for themes?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a graphic design question

Comment: @DA01: We allow questions about website design. While this may not be the best place to ask this kind of question, because the focus is on looking for a specific template, I don't think it will get any traction on Webmasters or Web Applications in the SE network. It might as well be asked here. I'm going to let it stand, but if any of the other @moderators disagree with me, then so be it.

Comment: I agree that website design is very much graphic design. And I suppose 'looking for a template' can fit that. I'd just hate to see 100 questions a day from people looking for a particular template.

Comment: @DA01: You mean like the myriad "What font is this? (See image)" questions we already have? Or the "What is this technique called?" questions? Or the "How do I [insert task here] in [application of choice]" questions? It's going to happen whether we want it to or not. The best thing you can do, really, is tag them and make sure those tags are in your "Ignored Tags" list.

Comment: Ya know, them more I think about it, I agree. It's valid. I'm going to tweak the question title a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had good success with WordPress themes found in [Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net/).

If I need **free** themes I turn my head to http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/ which also has a small collection of [commercial](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/commercial/) themes.

These (along with the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)) have been sufficient enough for me.

---

I usually try to [avoid dodgy "FREE THEMES HERE" sites](http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/).

Spoiler of the article: with keywords *free wordpress themes* 8 out of 10 sites included suspicious PHP code in their themes. Sane precaution is to scan the theme with [Theme Authenticity Checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tac/) and [Exploit Scanner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exploit-scanner/) plugins (no warranty).

Also the article names few *good* WP theme sites such as:

- [Graph Paper](http://graphpaperpress.com/)
- [WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/)

Based on my experiences non-free & well-made themes come out cheaper than free & hackish, if *your* time has any value.

---

And why not check [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) (a fellow SE site). It even has a community wiki titled [**Where can I download WordPress themes from?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29/1915)

Answer (score 3):

its hard to find exact layout,you can get a nearly theme on the net,There are some sites which provide free themes,please first **read there term and conditions**

1. http://www.justfreetemplates.com/
2. http://www.freethemelayouts.com/
3. http://www.themesbase.com/
4. http://www.themza.com/
5. http://www.themesandmods.net/

Hope this may help you and roll you back to the normal from urgent....:)

Answer (score 0):

Internet is flooded with the places that actually provide WordPress and Joomla themes just put a simple search online and you will surely end up with tons of good results. Beside the places recommended by other fellow members, one can also look at my favorite place called http://www.nulledlistings.com/ for getting these stuffs.